# A JQuery function for SVG, to execute 2nd animation as soon as, 1st animation completes?

Tags: html, jquery, css, svg, svg-animate

I applied the animation-delay technique, but to achieve a the handwriting effect animation, I had to cut the object wherever it intersects, and drew a path and converted it to a clipping mask, e.g. letter "W" divided into 4 parts and drew different paths for different part for the said above, and animating it, to give a clean handwriting effect, giving path a stroke width, It took me a lot more time as the font was too complicated.

Currently I am achieving the said animation using animation-delay, CSS function.

CSS Code

```
#W2-Path {
    animation-delay: .5s
}

#W3-Path {
    animation-delay: 1s
}

#W4-Path {
    animation-delay: 1.5s
}

#O-Path {
    animation-delay: 2s
}

#R1-Path-2 {
    animation-delay: 3.5s
}

#R2-Path-2 {
    animation-delay: 4s
}

#R3-Path-2 {
    animation-delay: 4.5s
}

#L1-Path-2 {
    animation-delay: 5s
}

#L2-Path-2 {
    animation-delay: 5.5s
}

#L3-Path-2 {
    animation-delay: 6s
}

#D1-Path {
    animation-delay: 6.5s
}

#D2-Path {
    animation-delay: 7s
}
```

I was thinking if there is any other way through which I can start the 2nd animation as the 1st animation completes, and it just keeps going on giving the animation more smoother effect and perfect timing, implementing JQuery?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ToxifiedM/pen/MWKeERr

Original Question: [How Can I Make SVG Text Animation Seamless And Accurate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62245574/13399106)

Linked Question 1: [To Control SVG CSS Based Animation Using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62359767/13399106)

Linked Question 2: [To Control The Speed Of Multiple SVG Elements Using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62374719/13399106)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering only for the latter W

I've changed the svg code you have, because it can be done in a more simple way.

You are wrapping every line in 2 groups. I'm using just the lines. Also you are using  `style="clip-path: url(#clip-path)"` I've transformed this to a presentational attribute like so: `clip-path="url(#clip-path)"` because in javascript I want to set the `animation-delay` as inline style for the lines.

An other change: I'm using `stroke-dasharray: 8` and `stroke-dashoffset: 8` since 8 is the length of the lines for the letter W. I know the length of the lines because I've used the `getTotalLength()` method.

The `stroke` and the `stroke-width` are set only once for the group since the lines for the letter have the same style.

The javascript is selecting all the lines in a group and then is looping through the lines and setting the `animation-delay:${i*1}s` where i is the nth line. Please observe that the order of the lines in the group is from the first to the 4-th  and not vice versa as you have them in your code.

```js
let Wls = document.querySelector("#W").querySelectorAll("line");//all the lines in the W group

Wls.forEach((l,i)=>{
// for each line in the W group
// set the style attribute
  l.setAttribute("style", `animation-delay:${i*1}s`)
})
```

```css
body {
 background: white;
}

svg {
  width: 90vh; 
  border:solid;
}


#W line{
  stroke-dasharray: 8;
  stroke-dashoffset: 8;
  animation: letter-animation 1s linear forwards;
}


@keyframes letter-animation {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 8;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg id="WOYP" viewBox="0 0 9 9">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-44" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W4" d="M11.676,16.41l.234.578c.236-.631.477-1.261.715-1.891q.222-.6.449-1.188t.409-1.063q.181-.476.308-.8c.084-.214.136-.348.156-.4s.05-.12.066-.16a.594.594,0,0,1,.061-.111.754.754,0,0,1,.086-.1.768.768,0,0,1,.151-.11h-1.03c.121.053.192.117.212.19a.481.481,0,0,1-.04.291c0,.007-.025.079-.076.216s-.118.319-.2.546-.18.483-.287.767-.216.573-.323.867Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-45" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W3" d="M11.675,16.358Zm0,0h0l.011.029h0l.232.575c-.152.4-.311.82-.474,1.252L10.176,15.07q-.242-.6-.478-1.183t-.433-1.058q-.2-.474-.333-.793c-.09-.213-.146-.343-.166-.389a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-.176-.27.774.774,0,0,0-.348-.209h1.833a.3.3,0,0,0-.221.239.9.9,0,0,0,.03.35c0,.006.027.076.08.209s.123.308.207.524.179.464.287.744.218.562.332.848Q11.179,15.089,11.675,16.358Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-46" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W2" d="M9.139,16.411l.234.578c.236-.632.477-1.261.715-1.891q.222-.6.45-1.189t.408-1.062c.122-.318.224-.584.308-.8s.137-.347.157-.4l.065-.16a.556.556,0,0,1,.061-.11.7.7,0,0,1,.086-.1.8.8,0,0,1,.151-.11h-1.03c.121.054.192.117.213.191a.488.488,0,0,1-.041.29c0,.007-.025.079-.076.216s-.117.319-.2.546-.179.483-.287.768-.216.573-.323.867Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-47" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W1" d="M9.138,16.358Zm0,0h0l.012.029h0l.233.575q-.229.6-.475,1.252L7.639,15.07q-.242-.6-.478-1.183t-.433-1.058q-.2-.474-.332-.793l-.166-.389a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-.177-.27.764.764,0,0,0-.347-.209H7.539a.305.305,0,0,0-.222.239.938.938,0,0,0,.03.35c0,.006.027.076.081.209s.122.308.206.524.18.464.287.744.218.562.332.848Q8.642,15.089,9.138,16.358Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g id="W" stroke="#003668" stroke-width="2">
    <line x1="0.93" y1="0.482" x2="3.873" y2="7.937" clip-path="url(#clip-path-47)" />
    <line x1="3.088" y1="7.937" x2="5.966" y2="0.482" clip-path="url(#clip-path-46)" />
    <line x1="3.481" y1="0.482" x2="6.424" y2="7.937" clip-path="url(#clip-path-45)" />
    <line x1="5.639" y1="7.937" x2="8.517" y2="0.482" clip-path="url(#clip-path-44)" />
  </g>

</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> So when I was actually trying to implement it, I got on the letter "O", its a path not a line, I tried your method, its not appearing for path, what can be done for that any clue?

In this case you'll have to animate the path. This time you don't need a different css animation and since the final value for the `stroke-dashoffset` is 0 you don't need a different animation. However you'll need to calculate the path's total length to use it for the path's `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffse`. In this case is 20.4.

```js
let Wls = document.querySelector("#W").querySelectorAll("line")

Wls.forEach((l,i)=>{
  l.setAttribute("style", `animation-delay:${i*1}s`)
})
```

```css
body {
 background: white;
}
svg {
  width: 90vh; 
  border:solid;
  overflow:visible;
}
#W line{
  stroke-dasharray: 8;
  stroke-dashoffset: 8;
  animation: letter-animation 1s linear forwards;
}

#O path{
  stroke-dasharray: 20.4;
  stroke-dashoffset: 20.4;
  animation: letter-animation 1s linear forwards;
  animation-delay:4.5s
}


@keyframes letter-animation {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg id="WOYP" viewBox="0 0 29 9">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-44" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W4" d="M11.676,16.41l.234.578c.236-.631.477-1.261.715-1.891q.222-.6.449-1.188t.409-1.063q.181-.476.308-.8c.084-.214.136-.348.156-.4s.05-.12.066-.16a.594.594,0,0,1,.061-.111.754.754,0,0,1,.086-.1.768.768,0,0,1,.151-.11h-1.03c.121.053.192.117.212.19a.481.481,0,0,1-.04.291c0,.007-.025.079-.076.216s-.118.319-.2.546-.18.483-.287.767-.216.573-.323.867Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-45" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W3" d="M11.675,16.358Zm0,0h0l.011.029h0l.232.575c-.152.4-.311.82-.474,1.252L10.176,15.07q-.242-.6-.478-1.183t-.433-1.058q-.2-.474-.333-.793c-.09-.213-.146-.343-.166-.389a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-.176-.27.774.774,0,0,0-.348-.209h1.833a.3.3,0,0,0-.221.239.9.9,0,0,0,.03.35c0,.006.027.076.08.209s.123.308.207.524.179.464.287.744.218.562.332.848Q11.179,15.089,11.675,16.358Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-46" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W2" d="M9.139,16.411l.234.578c.236-.632.477-1.261.715-1.891q.222-.6.45-1.189t.408-1.062c.122-.318.224-.584.308-.8s.137-.347.157-.4l.065-.16a.556.556,0,0,1,.061-.11.7.7,0,0,1,.086-.1.8.8,0,0,1,.151-.11h-1.03c.121.054.192.117.213.191a.488.488,0,0,1-.041.29c0,.007-.025.079-.076.216s-.117.319-.2.546-.179.483-.287.768-.216.573-.323.867Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id="clip-path-47" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)">
      <path id="W1" d="M9.138,16.358Zm0,0h0l.012.029h0l.233.575q-.229.6-.475,1.252L7.639,15.07q-.242-.6-.478-1.183t-.433-1.058q-.2-.474-.332-.793l-.166-.389a1.8,1.8,0,0,0-.177-.27.764.764,0,0,0-.347-.209H7.539a.305.305,0,0,0-.222.239.938.938,0,0,0,.03.35c0,.006.027.076.081.209s.122.308.206.524.18.464.287.744.218.562.332.848Q8.642,15.089,9.138,16.358Z" />
    </clipPath>

    <clipPath id="clip-path-43">
      <path id="clipO" d="M22.38,14.637v.026h0v.081l0,.023a3.231,3.231,0,0,1-.367,1.385,3.556,3.556,0,0,1-.9,1.089,3.814,3.814,0,0,1-1.2.655,3.724,3.724,0,0,1-1.289.2,3.869,3.869,0,0,1-1.4-.3,3.818,3.818,0,0,1-1.169-.756,3.474,3.474,0,0,1-.791-1.133A3.228,3.228,0,0,1,15,14.763v-.119h0v-.022h0V14.6h0v-.047h0v-.024h0V14.38a3.256,3.256,0,0,1,.273-1.138,3.554,3.554,0,0,1,.756-1.109,3.749,3.749,0,0,1,2.8-1.073,4.05,4.05,0,0,1,1.265.257A3.668,3.668,0,0,1,21.241,12a3.433,3.433,0,0,1,.836,1.113,3.107,3.107,0,0,1,.3,1.237l0,.021v.131h0v.025h0v.025h0v.052h0v.025ZM21.265,14.4a3.982,3.982,0,0,0-.18-1.025,2.913,2.913,0,0,0-.529-.99,2.287,2.287,0,0,0-.821-.628,2.492,2.492,0,0,0-1.043-.218,2.667,2.667,0,0,0-1.038.2,2.42,2.42,0,0,0-.826.569,2.593,2.593,0,0,0-.549.905,3.436,3.436,0,0,0-.2,1.085v.232h0v.024h0V14.6h0v.024h0v.023h0v.025l0,.023v.027a3.52,3.52,0,0,0,.228,1.105,2.93,2.93,0,0,0,.615.98,2.5,2.5,0,0,0,1.778.762,2.549,2.549,0,0,0,1.023-.2,2.313,2.313,0,0,0,.811-.584,2.739,2.739,0,0,0,.534-.915,3.439,3.439,0,0,0,.188-1.021v-.185h0v-.044h0V14.6h0v-.022h0v-.022h0v-.022h0v-.022h0V14.4Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g id="W" stroke="#003668" stroke-width="2">
    <line x1="0.93" y1="0.482" x2="3.873" y2="7.937" clip-path="url(#clip-path-47)" />
    <line x1="3.088" y1="7.937" x2="5.966" y2="0.482" clip-path="url(#clip-path-46)" />
    <line x1="3.481" y1="0.482" x2="6.424" y2="7.937" clip-path="url(#clip-path-45)" />
    <line x1="5.639" y1="7.937" x2="8.517" y2="0.482" clip-path="url(#clip-path-44)" />
  </g>

  <g id="O" stroke="#003668" stroke-width="2" fill="none">
    <path id="OPath" d="M18.657,11.3a3.1,3.1,0,0,0-2.289.981,3.448,3.448,0,0,0-.458,3.858,2.78,2.78,0,0,0,2.747,1.7,2.961,2.961,0,0,0,2.813-1.7,3.514,3.514,0,0,0-.458-3.858A3.055,3.055,0,0,0,18.657,11.3Z" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)" clip-path="url(#clip-path-43)" />
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks again @enxaneta, I'll surely give this solution a try, and will get back to you here, you are really a genius.

Comment: So when I was actually trying to implement it, I got on the letter "O", its a path not a line, I tried your method, its not appearing for path, what can be done for that any clue?

Comment: <g id="O" stroke="#003668" stroke-width="2">
  <path d="M18.657,11.3a3.1,3.1,0,0,0-2.289.981,3.448,3.448,0,0,0-.458,3.858,2.78,2.78,0,0,0,2.747,1.7,2.961,2.961,0,0,0,2.813-1.7,3.514,3.514,0,0,0-.458-3.858A3.055,3.055,0,0,0,18.657,11.3Z" transform="translate(-5.561 -10.291)" clip-path="url(#clip-path-43)" />
</g>

Comment: Hey @enxaneta Now I am getting this, just one final thing, how to remove the length of the path, using jquery, then I can surely combine this altogether.

Comment: I don't understand you. Why would you need to remove the length of the path?

Comment: No, I meant how to calculate the path and line total length.

Comment: As I've commented in my answer, In order to get the path's length you can use the [getTotalLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) method. This will give you a number with many decimal points. For the css you can round this to 2 or 3 decimals

Comment: Thanks aton, It was a great solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215683/discussion-between-yuvraj-singh-and-enxaneta).